# How To Reference Chart Objects within a Table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a report in Word with text and images/charts organized into tables.

I'm trying to set it so that a user can hide/show these tables by pressing a ToggleButton control on top of each table. I've set up the following VBA code for the buttons:

```
Sub ToggleCommand(btn As MSForms.ToggleButton, Optional TableNumber As Integer)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim objShape As InlineShape

Dim i As Integer

Dim NumberOfRows As Integer

NumberOfRows = ActiveDocument.Tables(TableNumber).Rows.Count

For i = 2 To NumberOfRows

  With ActiveDocument.Tables(TableNumber).Rows(i)

    If .HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly Then
      .HeightRule = wdRowHeightAuto
      btn.Caption = "Hide"
      .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
      .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
      .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle

    Else
      btn.Caption = "Show"
      .HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly
      .Height = ".5"
      .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
      .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
      .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone

  End If

  End With

Next i

lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The code will show/hide rows without any issue. However as mentioned, the table contain charts linked to Excel. So the code will collapse the rows of the table and hide the text, but the charts and images will still be visible and aren't collapsed along with the rows.

How can I set the code so that it will be able to hide the charts along with the rows?